# is there any way to get the sum of the product of euler's number and an integer, where the integer can range upto 10^6000?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, eulers-number

So I tried using BigDecimal which is giving me the value of Euler's number up to 50 decimal points. But since the constraint value is this high the number can range from 1 to 10^6000, and hence I am not getting any precision(making it optimal is another issue). Here is the block of code:

```
for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
 // i is the integer value and bd is the value of the euler's number, so below i am multiplying the value of i with the euler's number
 BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(i).multiply(bd);
 //Here i am taking floor of the above calculated value
 x.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
 //and here sum is floor[1*euler's no] + floor[2*euler's number] + ... + floor[n*euler's number] 
 sum += x.intValue();
}
```

Comment: What is `sum`? You might need to make that a BigDecimal as well.

Comment: The code snippet suggests you want to sum up 10^6000 numbers: good luck with that.

Comment: I first wanted to suggest using the formula `(n*(n+1) / 2)` and multiplying it with bd *once*, and then truncating, but that did not take into account that you need to add the the floor values, so 1*e would become 2, 2*e would become 5, giving a subtotal of 7, etc.while 3*e would become 8, giving an error of 1 already. You will have to loop, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to compute Euler's number (i.e. `e`) to greater precision.

The answer would be to implement an algorithm that converges rapidly.  With a little bit of research, I found this page on ["Calculating the Value of e"](http://www.intmath.com/exponential-logarithmic-functions/calculating-e.php).  At the bottom, it describes Brothers Formula:

```
e =​ Sum(n=0, n=​∞​​​, (2n+2)​​ / (2n+1)!​​ )
```

which converges very rapidly.  You could code that in Java using BigDecimal to calculate to any number of digits precision that you need.

See also:

- Brothers, H.J. 2004. [Improving the convergence of Newton's series approximation for e](http://www.brotherstechnology.com/docs/icnsae_(cmj0104-300dpi).pdf). College Mathematics Journal 35(January):34-39.

which (if I understood it correctly!) gives a more complicated formula that converges even more rapidly.

Comment: You understood correctly. The link to the pdf is very valuable, thanks. I've been looking for something like it, and there is not much (or at least not much I could read and follow) on that subject..